# Error occurred during initialization of VM Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\Ilya agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: java, intellij-idea, testng

I've got a problem while using TestNg run configuration in my Intellij IDE. I'm using JDK 11.0.17 and TestNg 7.4.0 and caught this type of error while compiling my test class

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Users\Ilya agent library failed to init: instrument
```

When I look at my run configuration I can see this:
[Run config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6JqY.png)

but if I change classpath of module to "no module" it works good, but looks not so well in run config

I tried to run test class with TestNg run configuration and caught an error

Comment: Do you use any build tool (Maven, Gradle)? Is it reproducible with some sample project that you could share?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven 3.8.6. Unfortunatelly no, I can't share this kind of projects((

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: Yes it is, with projects on java 11. On Java 8 samples it works good

Comment: Is it possible to provide any sample project?